# Вывести строку без html-тэгов, но оставить их содержимое

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть код который выводит первую строку из файла:

```
$fopen=@file($file);
$need="0";  
$texter =  $fopen[$need];
```

Выводиться строка из `html` файла прямо с тегами.

Как вывести строку без символов `<>`?

---

Пример строки:

```
<!-- text -->
```

Вывод:

```
text
```

Comment: ну например использовать удаление тегов с помощью strip_tags()

Comment: Можно было, но он не выводит закомментированные строки, а мне как раз наоборот надо

Comment: Можно привести пример строки и какой должен быть конечный результат? Возможно [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) вам поможет

Comment: Добавил в вопрос пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью одного регулярного выражения удалить и html-комментарии, и html-теги:

```
$str = '<h4>Заголовок</h4> <!-- text --> <p style="color: red;">Параграф</p>';

echo preg_replace('~(?:<!--\s*|\s*-->|</?[a-z\d]+[^>]*>)~', '', $str);
```

Comment: Спасибо, отлично сработало

Comment: @rorry47 я немного подкорректировал ответ, на случай если в тегах будут прописаны какие либо атрибуты.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так:

```
$clearString = '';
if (preg_match('/<\!--(.*)-->/i'), $texter, $matches) {
    $clearString = trim($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: А если там будет `<span>`?

Comment: @Hast у нормальных тегов нет символа `!`? как и `--`

Comment: @DaemonHK как я понял, автору вопроса нужно удалять вообще все тэги, в том числе и комменты (но оставлять их содержимое).

Comment: @Hast Вы правы. Первая строка закомментирована, и нужно вывести ее содержимое.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала убираем регуляркой все комменты, но оставить их содержимое. Затем остатки подчищаем функцией [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php).

```
<?php

$str = '<!-- text --> no tag test <span>span text</span> some other<br />text <!----> <!-- another comment -->';

$str = preg_replace('/<!--(.*?)-->/i', '$1', $str);
echo strip_tags($str);
```

Выведет:

```
 text  no tag test span text some othertext   another comment
```